# Escoger los k valores mas chicos en un vector

Tags: r, vectores, funcion

Hay alguna función en R, que dado un vector de números reales me pueda seleccionar los k valores más chicos y me indique los indices de la posición?.

Answer (score 0):

La función `rank` puede hacer lo que necesitas. Por ejemplo

```
# genero un vector de 20 números de una distribución normal 
x <- rnorm(20)
# los rangos son
rank(x)
# k menores valores de x son
x[rank(x) <= k]
# una función que haga eso
mi_rango <- function(x, k) {x[rank(x) <= k]}
# ejemplo
y <- rnorm(100)
mi_rango(y, 10)
```

Como tarea, puedes hacer que la función devuelva una lista con los k menores valores de y pero ordenados de menor a mayor junto con los índices de la posción original, etc...